# store private members as it is in c++, using write function

Tags: c++

```
class test{
    int x;
    public:
        //public functions getx() and putx()
};
void main()
{
fstream file;
test ob;
file.open("test.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
file.write((char *)&ob,sizeof(ob));
file.close();
}
```

When this code is executed, suppose the value of x in the current object is assigned as 1 using `getx()` function, the character corresponding to ascii value 1 gets stored in the text file, instead of the numeric 1. how to solve this?

Comment: You will need to write a serialization function for your class.

Comment: to convert the numeric 1 to its corresponding ascii ?

Comment: What you do _is_ storing the private members "as they are", which is of course _not_ a decimal representation of integer numbers but a binary format.

Comment: You might want to upgrade your compiler. `void main` doesn’t compile on any modern compiler, as far as I know.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you mean by your question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... i got you point folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you assigning x with getx()? I would expect putx(int x) to be used for assignment. In any case, you can write int to file using

```
ofstream file;
...
file << (int)getx();
```

Or, like @Oli Charleswoth said, write a serialization function that does this inside your class.

Similar to your question: [Writing multiple variable types to a text file using ofstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147337/writing-multiple-variable-types-to-a-text-file-using-ofstream)